# AS3 - Saving Many (Large) Files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am creating a flash game, and I need the game to be able to save a variety of files for any given play-through, some of which could hold as many as 5,000 unique data points for randomly generated content.  I have several questions:

**1.** Is there a limit to the number of files a flash game can save/load?  In a truly extreme case it may approach a few hundred files, if somebody has been playing the game for a very long time, though only a few (3-5) should ever need to be loaded into memory simultaneously.

**2.** Is a shared object appropriate for that much data?

**3.** If a shared object is inappropriate, is an XML file an acceptable alternative?  How about a raw .txt file which I could parse out using regular expressions?

**4.** At the max, with about 5,000 data points, it would actually be about 50,000-250,000 characters of text (depending on file medium) that, when loaded, would be broken down into nested vectors.  I don't want users to suffer from load times more than a second or so *at worst* when loading one of these files.  Is that realistic?

Help with any of these questions is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A flash game can't upload/download user files by it's own. It can only provide a dialog for a user to load a file or to save some information as a file. Use FileReference class for that.
The only thing that is accessible to the program is SharedObject -> [SharedObject reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html)
It can store up to 10Mb of data, but the user can change the limit without notice. Just right click on any flash window and you will see the options of the storage.

Comment: Is there a way, once a user has approved the program's access to a certain file, to access it freely in the future?

Comment: No, because there is no way for FP runtime to directly access local file system. The only way to access a file is to upload it using open file dialog. Ofc, you could always save data on the server - that won't require opening any dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answers are 
1: No limit but more files means more file dialogues.
2: Yep
3: You could store an XML or Text in a SharedObject
4: Depending on your loading process this should take up 50-250Kb and load fairly fast.

If you take a look at most flash gaming websites a lot of the applications that do save data use the SharedObject.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

It does store a limited amount of information though. If you plan on storing a lot of information then FileReference is what you are looking for, though that will only work for one file at a time if I am not mistaken.

Your best bet would be to store the various information in either an XML or your own encoded format. I like to encode information into a byte array. It a bit tougher to manage, but storage is much easier and smaller. Text like XML tends to get pretty bloated unless you gzip it or do something similar.

In general for every 1,000 characters expect about 1Kb of uncompressed disk space usage. So in your case you would take up to 250Kb. Not even a MB so a single shared object will do the trick